# Using Hibernate To Save Failed

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

### Using Hibernate To Save Failed

When I use hibernate to save an entity to the database. Althogh there is no exception or error in the console(I've corretly configured log4j).
There is no an insert sql in the console and there is no data in the database.

It's strange, I can successfully use hibernate to get data from database and there are select sql in the console.

BTW.I used myeclipse reverse engeering to build the model and hbm file.

I tried several ways but failed:

1. It's not about transaction,I commit in TeamService.
2. I set log4j.properties to see all the errors ,but there is no exception.
3. I tried to assign the entity I need to save to a new instance, but still, no data in
4. I thought it is about composite-id in hbm ,but I don't know how to fix it .

**Here's my Team entity(I eliminated the irrelevant part)**

```
    private TeamId id;
    private Classes classes;
```

**Here's my Team hbm**

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="edu.wzy.model.Team" table="team" catalog="test3" >
        <composite-id name="id" class="edu.wzy.model.TeamId">
            <key-property name="TNo" type="java.lang.Integer">
                <column name="T_NO" />
            </key-property>
            <key-many-to-one name="SUser" class="edu.wzy.model.SUser">
                <column name="S_ID" />
            </key-many-to-one>
        </composite-id>
        <many-to-one name="classes" class="edu.wzy.model.Classes" fetch="select">
            <column name="C_ID" not-null="true">
            </column>
        </many-to-one>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**Here's my TeamService**

```
public class TeamServiceImpl implements TeamService
{
    TeamDAO teamDAO=new TeamDAO();
    public void save(Team t)
    {
        Session session=HibernateUtil.getCurrentSession();
        session.getTransaction().begin();
        teamDAO.save(t);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
    }
}
```

**Here's my Dao**

```
public void save(Team transientInstance)
{
    try
    {
        getSession().save(transientInstance);
        log.debug("save successful");
    } catch (RuntimeException re)
    {
        log.error("save failed", re);
        throw re;
    }
}
```

**Here's my action(I eliminated the irrelevant part)**

```
public class TeamAction extends BaseAction implements ModelDriven<Team>
{
    public String add()
    {
        Classes classes = classesService.findbyid(team.getClasses().getId());
        Set s = team.getClasses().getStudents();
        Iterator it = s.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext())
        {studentid = (String) it.next();}
        Student student = studentService.findbyid(Integer.parseInt(studentid));
        Team t=new Team();
        t.setId(team.getId());
        classes.getStudents().add(student);
        t.setClasses(classes);
        teamService.save(t);
        return SUCCESS;
    }

}
```

Comment: is your Team#id auto_increment in db? is it `<composite-id name="id" class="edu.wzy.model.TeamId">` or `<composite-id name="id" class="edu.wzy.model.Team">`?

Comment: 1.  No, Team#id is not  auto_increment in db.2.  Is `<composite-id name="id" class="edu.wzy.model.TeamId">` because TeamId is another class storing id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found where the problem is.
The problem is that the save method is not in the same session that  `TeamService` provide.
I made a mistake. 
The Dao classes are generated by machine, they extends a fathre class which has a method to generate session. But I also create a class `HibernateUtil` to generate session.
So save method is not in the same session as Service,which lead to failed saving.
The answer to this question is to modify the method in Dao.

```
public void save(Classes transientInstance)
{
    log.debug("saving Classes instance");
    try
    {
        HibernateUtil.getCurrentSession().save(transientInstance);
        log.debug("save successful");
    } catch (RuntimeException re)
    {
        log.error("save failed", re);
        throw re;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `session.flush()` before commit. Just like

```
 public class TeamServiceImpl implements TeamService {
        TeamDAO teamDAO = new TeamDAO();

        public void save(Team t) {
            Session session = HibernateUtil.getCurrentSession();
            session.getTransaction().begin();
            teamDAO.save(t);
            session.flush();
            session.clear();
            session.getTransaction().commit();
            session.close();
        }
       }
```